# Convert a dataframe with multiple rows into one row using pandas?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Having the following dataframe,

```
      0      1      2
A    0.2    0.4    0.6
B    0.1    0.1    0.3
```

How to achieve this transformation, while merging the row index with column name?

```
     A_0    A_1    A_2    B_0    B_1    B_2
0    0.2    0.4    0.6    0.1    0.1    0.3
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `stack` followed by a transpose to get the DataFrame in the right shape, then format the column names as appropriate.

```
df = df.stack().to_frame().T
df.columns = ['{}_{}'.format(*c) for c in df.columns]
```